# Count down timezone differences (LDN - NY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, momentjs, countdown

I need to build a count down (clock) in jQuery with the New York (NY) time as a starting time. And will send a link to users located in London (LDN). So the event will start in NY, that's why the starting time is based on NY.

I would like to use the momentJS library to calculate the diff timezones. But I don't know what are the things I have to deal with.

Do you think I can use something like this (especially the opentime and ct):

```
var opentime = moment.tz("2018-07-01 09:00:00", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', "America/New_York");

var ct = moment.tz("Europe/London");
var dur = moment.duration(opentime.diff(ct));

$(".count_d").find("span").html(opentime.diff(ct, 'days'));
$(".count_h").find("span").html(dur.hours());
$(".count_m").find("span").html(dur.minutes());
$(".count_s").find("span").html(dur.seconds());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you care for different timezones if you need a _countdown_? You can calculate everything in timezone of your choice and then work only with `duration` variable.

Comment: It's unclear what you are inquiring about.  Please ask a clear and concise question.  Thanks.